# RESTful url for a tree categorized resource

Tags: url, rest, tree, hierarchical-data

I have a classical data model where items are categorized in a hierarchical tree structure:

```
example.com/myanimals/pet/dog/{mydog_ID}
example.com/myanimals/pet/cat/{mycat_ID}
example.com/myanimals/birds/{mybirds_ID}
```

I want to expose a RESTful API addressable by URLs like above.

- When the last element of URL is an item I have to display the item and possibly the sub-categories of the item category
- If the last element is a category, I have to display a list of its items and its sub-categories.

Then two different behaviours if I'm addressing a category or an item.
I'm using the RESTLet library on java, now my question are:

1. Is it a RESTful approach to address a resource by a (theoretical) infinite path of categories?
2. What's the best way to model URL in a RESTful way for a data model like that?

Another problem could be that With that design I have to parse all the characters after *animals*, then test if the last element is a category itself or an item, and finally handle the resource with the appropriate representetion. This implies also that I have one namespace for category and item, and I have to ensure that categories and items have unique names.

**UPDATE**

Ok finally I ended up with this design:

```
/animals -> read all animals
GET /animals/categories/cat1/cat2 -> read all animals (as a list) and/or subcategories of cat2 (parameterized with query param)
/animals/name -> handle specific animal
/animals/categories -> read root categories
PUT/DELETE/POST /animals/categories/cat1/cat2 -> handle all subcategories of cat2
/animals/tags/tag -> read list of all animals labeled with this tag
```

- In the first design the namespace categories and animals **were in conflict**:
  there was a critical problem for routing a creation element: POST /informationmodels should have been be routed to animal creation or category creation?
- With the file-system like URL design /animals/cat1/cat2/.../animalname the client don't now if it's getting an animal item or a category and then a list of items.

The solution above seems to handle correctly these issues, you only have to know that no animal with name *categories* or *tags* will be addressable because these are reserved keywords.

Comment: I'm not sure I see your question here.  Do you want to know how to do this (in which case we need to know platform/language)?  Whether it's the right approach? (In which case you might consider http://programmers.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @AndrasZoltan it's Java, RESTLet. He mentioned that in the question.

Comment: @Tom right; yes.  Up too late last night it would seem :)  Even so I don't see an SO question at the moment.

Comment: Indeed, I cannot see a question either. Number 1. has a question mark but some words are missing or there's some grammatical error.

Comment: Corrected the question...sorry for my english. Anyway i'm finding a good way to design the URL that is the more possible RESTful.

Comment: Actually, the way you are doing it now seems right. It allows the client to request as many or as little resources as they need. If there's a problem with the size of the data, perhaps you could implement pagination like on the Facebook Graph API.

Comment: The only thing is that when a client input an url like /animals/pet/dog he don't know if it will get a list of animals or an animal, but with /animals/pet/dog/animal/mydog it is sure that it will get an animal...but i know is not straight like the first design